# How to change operator in filterToQuery function from eq. to ilike

Tags: react-admin

I'm trying to add a like filter to `AutocompleteInput` element, but it converts in a url `https://[host]/rest/v1/blocks?order=id.desc&offset=0&limit=1000&name=eq.%test%` with an operator `eq`.

```js
const filterToQuery = (searchText:string) => ({ 'name': `%${searchText}%`});
—
 <ReferenceInput source=“block_id" reference="blocks">
   <AutocompleteInput sx={{width: 1}} filterToQuery={filterToQuery} label="Block" optionText="name" />
 </ReferenceInput>
```

How to change 'eq.'  to 'ilike.' operator in the url to `https://[host]/rest/v1/blocks?order=id.desc&offset=0&limit=1000&name=ilike.%test%`?

Answer (score 1):

The query string is generated in your `DataProvider`, you can create your own local copy of the `DataProvider`
and change the formation of strings in the required methods (`getOne / getMany / getManyReference / ...`)

Comment: Your advice prompted me to dive deeper and I saw there @promitheus/ra-data-postgrest data provider that formates the url string. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have been using `@promitheus/ra-data-postgrest` data provider in-depth and it uses `@` notation for filters e.g. `name@like`. So that I needed something like that:

```js
const filterToQuery = (searchText:string) => ({ 'name@like': `${searchText}`});
```